# Change size of Mermaid.render generated SVG?

Tags: html, css, typescript, render, mermaid

I am attempting to render an SVG using mermaid in my Angular 8 project. Everything renders exactly as needed except my only issue is that the sizing is too small, and I am unable to override the max-width in my CSS. So I am trying to set a larger width in my TS file.

In my onIt() function in TS I have included the following:

```
mermaid.render("graphDiv", graphDefinition, (svgCode, bindFunctions) => {
        element.innerHTML = svgCode;
        bindFunctions(element);
      element.setAttribute("style", "max-width: 1000px !important")
      });
```

However, this does nothing to increase the max-width, which is being automatically set.

I have already tried changing "graphDiv" in CSS with no luck. Is it possible to override the preset width using typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override these settings in the styles.scss file of your Angular project. Like this:

```
svg#graphDiv {
 max-width: none !important;
}
```

This should override the mermaid settings.